# Relation Between Fetch using JavaScript and Fetch Using Python Requests

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, fetch-api

I have been trying to access an API using Python Requests and/or Scrapy but have been unsuccessful in logging in with a POST request. I decided to try my luck using a fetch command via JavaScript and was able to successfully log-in with the following code.

```
    fetch("https://vendoradmin.fashiongo.net/api/login", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en,en-US;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,es;q=0.7",
    "content-type": "text/plain",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"89\", \"Chromium\";v=\"89\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
  },
  "referrer": "https://vendoradmin.fashiongo.net/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "{\"username\":\"*****\",\"password\":\"*****\"}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
})
```

No matter how I've tried to set my headers and payload with my Python requests, I always receive and 500 status code, but I think I'm missing something. Is there anyone out there can do a literal translation of the above JS Fetch to a Python Request? or explain why this would work with JS but not with a Python Request?

The current Python request script I've been trying is below:

```
import requests

payload = {'username':'*****', 'password':'*****'}

headers = {
'Host': 'vendoradmin.fashiongo.net',
'Origin': 'https://vendoradmin.fashiongo.net/#/auth/login',
'Referrer':'https://vendoradmin.fashiongo.net/',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.post("https://vendoradmin.fashiongo.net/api/login", data = payload, headers = headers)
```

Comment: Instead of `data`, use the `json` kwarg. `data` makes the post form-encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `json` kwarg instead of the `data` kwarg:

```py
r = requests.post("https://vendoradmin.fashiongo.net/api/login", json = payload, headers = headers)
```

`data` makes the request form-encoded instead of using `application/json` as the content-type